# Rails - get distinct events, sorted by the start date of associated event instances

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I've spent several hours going through StackOverflow and playing around with this query, but still can't get it to work! Hopefully an expert here on SO can make the pain go away...

I have two models, Event and EventInstance. An Event has_many EventInstances.

What I want to do is easily get a list of Events (not EventInstances), where:

- Events are distinct and not repeated
- Events are sorted by the start_date of the nearest EventInstance
- Event instances have the attribute :active => true
- Only event instances that have a start date in the future are returned

I currently have the query

```
Event.joins(:event_instances).select('distinct events.*').where('event_instances.start_date >= ?', Time.now).where('event_instances.active = true')
```

This returns a list of events, but not sorted by date. Excellent - so I am almost there!

If I change the query to add this on the end:

```
.order('event_instances.start_date')
```

I get the error:

```
PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

So I moved it to the select statement:

```
select('distinct event_instances.start_date, events.*')
```

Now I get

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function count(date, events) does not exist
```

I've tried moving methods around, using includes, everything but I still can't get it to work. Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you please mention the fields of both models?

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
.order('event_instances.start_date')
```

to

```
.order(:event_instances.start_date)
```

or if you need descending order add the `.reverse_order` method to the end of the query

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact query which worked for my models Post and PostComments on both MySQL and PostgreSQL:
`Post.joins(:post_comments).select('distinct post_comments.body, post_comments.created_at').order('post_comments.created_at desc')`

So for you, it's equivalent should work too. If it still doesn't then please update your post with the fields of your model.